# ARC of Swift protocol objects

Tags: memory-management, swift, automatic-ref-counting, protocols

ARC is deinitializing my protocol objects that still have active references, is this a bug or is it expected behavior, and what is the workaround?

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    ...
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    ...
}

class ClassA {
    var protocolObject: SomeProtocol!
    ...
}


class ClassB {
    var x: SomeClass!

    func f() {
        self.x = SomeClass()
        var objA = ClassA()
        objA.protocolObject = self.x
    }
}
```

In this example, when objA is deinitialized, it attempts to deinitialize objA.protocolObject, even though there is still a reference active as objB.x. This causes a runtime error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. However, if ClassA is defined as follows:

```
class ClassA {
    var protocolObject: SomeClass
}
```

The code runs without error and protocolObject is not deinitialized. Any thoughts?

Comment: What beta are you running? That sample runs without issue for me in b7. The `ClassA` instance is deinitialized immediately upon return from `b.f()`, but I can call `println(b.x)` anytime after that without issue.

Comment: Same as Nate, no issue in Xcode b7

Comment: So I tried this simplified example and it does actually work for me... short of pasting several kloc I'm not sure how to show the actual malfunctioning code... I can say for sure that the one line change mentioned in the Q fixes it, so the bug seems to be tied to using the protocol type for the object. I also did an error output in the deinit call and the error does display

Comment: I actually get the deinit call twice sometimes because there are actually two classes, B and C (B is the owner of C), that have the var protocolObject: SomeProtocol declaration. They both seem to be attempting to deinit the protocol-typed object. I also created a new, unique object just to test this and make sure that I am not somehow destroying my references somewhere else in the program. The error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This bug seems to be resolved as of iOS8.0.

---

I'm experiencing the same problem, and have narrowed down to the issue to the protocol being defined as a Class-Only Protocol (i.e. `protocol XXX: class`).

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
}

// Note: Class-Only protocol
protocol BarProtocol: class {
    var name: String { get }
}

class Foo: FooProtocol {    
    let name: String = "Foo"
    deinit {
        println("\(name) deinit")
    }
}

class Bar: BarProtocol {
    let name: String = "Bar"    
    deinit {
        println("\(name) deinit")
    }
}

class Container {
    let foo: FooProtocol = Foo()
    let bar: BarProtocol = Bar()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let container = Container()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Prints 'Test: Foo'
        test(container.foo)

        // Prints 'Test: Bar', followed by 'Bar deinit'
        // subsequent access to the `bar` variable results in a crash
        test(container.bar)
    }

    func test(bar: BarProtocol) {
        println("Test: \(bar.name)")
    }

    func test(foo: FooProtocol) {
        println("Test: \(foo.name)")
    }

}
```

Current workaround is to either forgo using class-only protocol. I have filed a bug report to Apple, rdar://18287447.

Comment: This workaround was successful, thanks. Hopefully Apple will fix, otherwise can't declare these references as weak.